# In Java, is it possible to declare a field that can never become null?

Tags: java, null

Let's assume we define this Book class where we ensure that isbn can never be assigned a null value:

```java
public class Book {

  private String isbn;

  public Book(String isbn) {
    setIsbn(isbn);
  }

  public void setIsbn(String isbn) {
    if (isbn == null) {
      throw new NullPointerException();
    }

    this.isbn = isbn;
  }

  public String getIsbn() {
    return this.isbn;
  }

}
```

This prevents creation of a Book object where isbn is null but after a book object with a non-null isbn is created, we can modify the value via reflection and set it to null.

Is there anyway (using a trick or a Java feature) to prevent an instance of Book to ever exist in the memory where its isbn is null?

NB: this question is not about `Optional`s.

Comment: The other one is closed, this one lives.

Comment: Just make it `final`, and assign in the constructor with `this.isbn = Objects.requireNonNull(isbn)`. Edit: scratch that, missed reflection is an option

Comment: If you were using Kotlin, this would be a lot easier. I guess warning others with `@NotNull` is the closest you can get (short of making a compiler plugin)

Comment: Not in a compliant JVM. References are nullable.

Comment: Since your class is not serializable, the only way to make that field null is by reflection. You can prevent this using the `SecurityManager `. For example, extending the SecurityManager class you can deny using reflection at the application level

Comment: As an interesting factoid - Java 1.3/1.4 will throw an error when modifying final field with reflection.

Comment: @pafauk. 1) I don't want it to be immutable, I just want to make sure it can never be set to null. 2) Even making it final, as you have found out, one can change it to null via reflection, for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Technically references are nullable. Even though you can use `final` to make sure that the compiler won't let you leave a variable `null`, you can use reflection to remove its finality and set it to null.

If you count out reflection, then let's say native code or `Unsafe` or bytecode instrumentation or so on and so on. In the end, the internal representation allows nulls, so depending on how far you'll go there'll be a way to make a variable `null` if you **really** want to, unless you specify constraints about what's allowed/possible, such as whether a `SecurityManager` is involved.

If you're asking the question because you're afraid that your variable isn't safe enough from `NullPointerExceptions`, then using `final`, `Objects.requireNonNull()` and good design is enough.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to rule out reflection, the answer is no.

The only option you have is, installing a security manager which disallows reflection, but in which hostile environment do you expect your code to run? And even then, the user who starts the VM could add an agent, which can manipulate the bytecode.

So, as *total* security is concerned: no.